# Как в таймдельту передать 5 дней с помощью строки?

Tags: python, datetime

```py
from datetime import timedelta as td

type = "days"

td(type = 5)
```

Можно ли установить таймдельту 5 дней таким способом? Прям таким способ выдаёт ошибку.

Comment: Не используйте `type` в качестве имени переменной, это зарезервированное слово питона.

Answer (score 2):

А вы можете объяснить, почему именно "с помощью строки". Что-то мне кажется, что вам на самом деле надо просто передать значение в тот параметр, который задан строкой. И тогда это будет выглядеть вот так:

```
tp = "days"
if tp=="days":
    t=td(*(5,))
print(t)
```

Результат:

```
5 days, 0:00:00
```

Вариант 2. (Если ну очень нужно именно непосредственно *"с помощью строки"*):

```
tp = "days"
td(**{tp:5})
```